# Rで日本語ツイートの取得ができない

Tags: r, twitter, windows-10

Rで以下のコードでツイート取得しようとしたらエラーが出ます。
OSはWindows10で、Rstudioを使ってます。

**ソースコード**

```
searchTwitter(searchString = "#100歳までの計画", 
              n = 500,                 
              lang = "ja",             
              since = NULL,            
              until = NULL,            
              locale = NULL,           
              geocode = NULL,          
              sinceID = NULL,          
              maxID = NULL,            
              resultType = "mixed",    
              retryOnRateLimit = 120   
)
```

**エラー**

```
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = 
retryOnRateLimit,  :
  500 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
```

searchStringの所に、英語を入れるとエラーは起きません。
また日本語でも、3文字までならエラーが起きませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

```
iconv("#100歳までの計画","CP932","UTF-8")
```